# Tickmark using epplus

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc, ms-office, epplus

My problem is, when I am trying to generate my Excel file
I have some cells contains the tickmark symbol.

```
   using (ExcelRange Rng = wsSheet.Cells[col])
   {
     Rng.Value = Beneficiary.IDentityOrFamilyBookCheck;// this value is ü
     Rng.Style.Font.SetFromFont("Wingdings", 16);
     Rng.Style.Font.Charset = 178;
   }
```

in fact with the specified font and value it must appear as a check
but it is not

This is how it actually appears

[image: this is how it actually appears]

This is how it must appear

[image: this is how it must appear]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Charset is wrong. Try `Rng.Style.Font.Charset = 2;` It is always good to do some reverse engineering. In this case create an Excel file with the Font and symbol you want and read the Style within your program.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover the solution in my own way. Please note that Behnam's way is excellent also and can clarify the issue, but I did it in a different way.

1. I created an excel file containing the required symbol.
2. I changed the .xsls extension to .zip.
3. Iow I became able to show my excel file XML content and discover the actual `Rng.Style.Font.Charset`.